# Sort structure array in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, stdvector

I have a structure array (A[#]) named Sheep (since my task is about sheeps DNR). After I do whatever the task asked I am left with this struct :

```
struct Sheep 
{
    string Vardas;
    char Fragmentas[CMax]; 
    int atitikme = 0; 
};
```

and inside my it the data is:

```
(string Vardas) | (char Fragmentas[CMax]) | (int atitikme)
Baltukas   TAGCTT 3
Bailioji   ATGCAA 3 
Smarkuolis AATGAA 1
```

(char Fragmentas[CMax] won't be using so u don't have to look at it, I only named it to make it clear).

ALL of this data comes from U2.txt file and cant be manually typed in a code.

All its left to do is to sort it by these rules:

> 1. It goes from bigger to smaller by 'int atitikme'.
> 2. IF 'int atitikme' is equal then it will have to sort by 'A[#].Vardas in a in alphabetical order.

To sort it by 'int atitikme' I created a code:

```
string q;
char w[20];
int e;
for (int o = 0; o < n-1; o++) 
{
    for (int p = o+1; p < n-1; p++) 
    {
        if (A[p].atitikme > A[o].atitikme) 
        {
            // - Vardo Keitimas
            q = A[o].Vardas;
            A[o].Vardas = A[p].Vardas;
            A[p].Vardas = q;
            // - A[#].atitikme keitimas
            e = A[o].atitikme;
            A[o].atitikme = A[p].atitikme;
            A[p].atitikme = e;
            // - DNR farkmentu keitimas
            for (int r = 0; r < m; r++) 
            {
                w[r] = A[o].Fragmentas[r];
                A[o].Fragmentas[r] = A[p].Fragmentas[r];
                A[p].Fragmentas[r] = w[r];
             }
        }
    }
}
```

n = 4 | m = 6

How/what do i need to add to this code to make it go:

```
else if (A[p].atitikme == A[o].atitikme) 
{
    <code>
}
```

That if 'atitikme' is == to another 'atitikme' then A[p].Vardas and A[o].Vardas has to be sorted in an alphabetical order. but only those 2 from the whole array.

OR if its too hard to understand what I meant, could anyone post a code, in the answer box, were it would sort in a alphabetical order between 2 string's?

NOTE:
the whole line data

> (string Vardas) (char Fragmentas[CMax]) (int atitikme)

has to stay the same, only the place in the line has to be diffirent and sorted by those rules I mentioned before.

The output should be:

```
Bailioji   3
Baltukas   3
Smarkuolis 1
```

EDIT:
My current output is:

```
Baltukas   3
Bailioji   3
Smarkuolis 1
```

**P.s**. The task allows to use everything as-long as its C++ and does not have to create, or read, any other file.

Comment: why don't you use a std::vector and std::sort

Comment: can you use std::sort - or this is some C++ exercise about writing sort by yourself?

Comment: @Tyker I dont know how. I am a self c++ learning. Basicly i am doing my country's IT exams from previews years for fun and at the same time i learn something by either finding what i need online or getting help from others in real life.

Comment: @PiotrNycz In the task it is allowed to use what ever you want. sadly i do not know how this std::sort works. i tried it but i failed to accomplish what i need.

Comment: I really recommend that you start using english variable names. Makes communication far easier. Same goes for comments. Also, use descriptive variable names instead of single letters. If you look at your code one year later, you might have no idea what o or p were.

Comment: @Aziuth I understand. But my task is to use those variables and, since I am lithuanian, my comments and variables has to be in Lithuanian. Perhaps next time i post something I will have to translate all variables and comments to english.

Comment: @Lith I don't mean this simply for StackOverflow only. I mean this in general. Your code should always be english, no matter what your nationality is. I myself am not a native english speaker either and I do that. Right now, you might write a program all by yourself, but at some point you will probably be in a project with several nationalities. Then you want writing it in english to be a routine of yours.

Comment: @Aziuth I did not think about that. Thank you. I will use your advice in my other upcoming self made, or found on the internet that does not have specified what language to use.
Thank you again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I have used `std::vector<>` instead of array to store the sheeps. 
Secondly, using `std::sort()` and a `lambda` function, you can easily mention how you want to sort the elements in the `std::vector<>`/ `Sheeps`. That would be the easiest way to approach.

Here is the live code, in case of reviewing: https://www.ideone.com/ay7TWU

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Sheep
{
   std::string Vardas;
   std::vector<char> Fragmentas;
   int atitikme;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Sheep> vec =
   {
      {"Baltukas",  {'T','A','G','C','T','T'}, 3},
      {"Bailioji",  {'A','T','G','C','A','A'}, 3},
      {"Smarkuolis",{'A','A','T','G','A','A'}, 1},
      {"Hmarkuolis",{'A','A','T','G','A','A'}, 1},
      {"Kmarkuolis",{'A','A','T','G','A','A'}, 2}
   };

   std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const Sheep& lhs, const Sheep& rhs)
      {
         return (lhs.atitikme == rhs.atitikme) ? 
            lhs.Vardas < rhs.Vardas: // if atitikme's of sheeps are equal
            lhs.atitikme > rhs.atitikme; // if atitikme's of sheeps are not equal
      });

    for (const auto& it: vec)
        std::cout << it.Vardas << " " << it.atitikme << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Bailioji 3
Baltukas 3
Kmarkuolis 2
Hmarkuolis 1
Smarkuolis 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The best is to solve your problem one by one.

First - define the sorting order - see doc about - e.g. in [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)

So, you need functor class that defines your sorting order:

```
class SheepOrder
{
public:
    bool operator() ( const Sheep& left, const Sheep& right) const
    {
        // It goes from bigger to smaller by 'int atitikme'.
        if (left.atitikme > right.atitikme)
             return true;
        if (left.atitikme < right.atitikme)
             return false;

        //IF 'int atitikme' is equal then it will have to sort it in a in alphabetical order. 
        // I guess you meant Vardas
        return left.Vardas < right.Vardas;
    }
};
```

Now, having defined the order  - just use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) - it can be used with arrays - no problem:

```
Sheep sheeps[100];
// .. 
std::sort(std::begin(sheeps), std::end(sheeps), SheepOrder{});
```

or:

```
void sortSheeps(Sheep* array, std::size_t numOFSheeps)
{
    std::sort(array, array + numOfSheeps, SheepOrder{});
}
```

You can also use [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to make it easier to define sorting order (tuple has operator < by default if their elements have this operator too):

```
class SheepOrder
{
public:
    bool operator() ( const Sheep& left, const Sheep& right) const
    {
        return tieMembersForSorting(left) < tieMembersForSorting(right);
    }
private:
    static auto tieMembersForSorting( const Sheep& object)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(-object.atitikme, // - to revert order
                               std::ref(object.Vardas)); // ref - to not make copy of string
    } 
};
```

With `tieMembersForSorting` defined as free function - lambda could be used as well (as it will be just one liner):

```
    inline auto tieMembersForSorting( const Sheep& object)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(-object.atitikme, // - to revert order
                               std::ref(object.Vardas)); // ref - to not make copy of string
    } 

    std::sort(begin(...), end(...), [](Sheep const& left, Sheep const& right)
              { return tieMembersForSorting(left) < tieMembersForSorting(right); });
```

Comment: It is simpler to use `std::tie` instead of `std::make_tuple` and not to deal with `std::ref`

Comment: why not using a lambda instead of SheepOrder

Comment: @Slava - that's true - but I have to revert `atitikme` sorting order - then `std::tie` cannot be used

Comment: @Tyker - matter of style - that is too many lines for lambda - but with make_tuple - it could be done

Comment: It can, just do it in place without helper function and swap left and right

Comment: @Slava - yep, possible - but what about readability of that code - I would have to pass to `tieMembersForSorting` both - left and right... And w/o helper functions - duplications and hard to read code

Comment: You do not have to use `tieMembersForSorting` at all

Comment: @Slava I have to - unless I pretend that "Don't repeat yourself" is a rule that is not worth to follow

Comment: DRY doesn't mean only use an identifier once, it means have a single source of truth. `return std::tie(right.atitikme, left.Vardas) < std::tie(left.atitikme, right.Vardas);` is not repetitious

Comment: @Caleth - for me DRY means that when I have to change something - I do it in one place. If I have to change the order of sorting `atitikme, Vardas` to `Vardas, atitikme` - then I do it once - not twice...

Comment: I also take issue with `tieMembersForSorting` returning a `std::tuple<int, const std::string&>`. Call it `as_tuple` and/or have it return a (*cv*) `std::tuple<int&, std::string&>`

Comment: @Caleth `tie` in `tieMembersForSorting` means "bind(tie) some members from struct just for sorting". `tie` in this name does not have any relation to this method implementation. From your comment I guess you believe that function names shall have strict relation with function implementations.  Moreover returning from such function `int&` would suggest that I allow to modify returned reference what is not true.   For such purpose its irrelevant if I return `int` or `const int&`. So I select just `int` - for its simplicity. For `std::string` - because it is heavy object - I select const-ref.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort shows you how to use `std::sort`.

You write a function `bool less_than(const Sheep& a, const Sheep& b)` that represents the order of two sheep and then simply call `std::sort(container.begin(), container.end(), less_than);`, with `container` being something like a vector of Sheep.

Edit: The function written out:

```
bool less_than(const Sheep& a, const Sheep& b)
{
    if(a.atitikme != b.atitikme) return a.atitikme < b.atitikme;
    return a.Vardas < b.Vardas;
}
```